# Joomla - Different forum per page

Tags: joomla, forums

I'm fairly new to Joomla - so hopefully this isn't too simple.

My client would like to have a separate discussion forums per "Page". For instance, say you user groups Group 1, Group 2 and Group 3 and have Page 1, Page 2, and Page 3. Each Page will have a discussion forum that will only be accessible by the corresponding Group. To handle the permissions I've been using noixACL, and that seems like it will do the job.

My problem is I'm not able to create separate forums with any of the components I've tried yet. The two forum components I've liked are [ccBoard](http://codeclassic.org/) and [Kunena](http://www.kunena.com/) Forum. If I create a new link for either one it will only create a page that has all the forums and categories listed, I really need to have a link per forum so I could place the link on the separate Pages.

If anyone has any suggestions, or know of any modules that will display only a single forum/category I would appreciate it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you install say, phpbb and bridge it with joomla with rokbridge.

On phpbb make each forum private and hidden from the other groups, so its only 1 single forum but each group can only see 1 section. so it will be only 1 link but the content will depend on what the group permission has.

http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokbridge

http://www.phpbb.com/kb/article/create-a-private-forum/